# How to reapply symmetry in sculpting?

Tags: mirror, sculpting

I have been sculpting a human head *using dynamic topology*. I've been primarily sculpting on the right side of the picture below. At some point, the mirror got messed up and shows the eye on the left side incorrectly.

[image]

How do I reapply the mirror from the right side of the picture above to the left side?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Dyntopo, then just click the "Symmetrize" button under the Dyntopo settings panel. Just make sure that the "Direction" menu is set correctly. The default is "-X to +X". If the side that you want to keep is in the "-X" direction (away from the red arrow on the manipulator) then leave it how it is. If not, change it so that the first direction is the side you want to keep, and the second direction is the side that got messed up. This way, you don't have to leave your workflow and you can stay in Sculpt Mode.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! That fixed my problem very quickly.

Comment: Blender 2.83. It was not under that; it was in the [X][Y][Z] button's drop-down menu. Or in in "Symmetry" section of the right drawer menu.

Answer (score 4):

Change to Edit Mode select the whole mesh, hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type **Symmetrize**, then hit <kbd>F6</kbd> and chose the axis of symmetry.

[image]